# VB6 program works in the IDE but compiled exe doesn't reflect changes

Tags: vb6

I just started my new job and was assigned a simple task: change an SQL statement in a VB6 program, test it, publish the changes.  All I did was change the AS field of SELECT COLUMN AS *NAME*.  I made a new EXE, and it doesn't show the new changes.  However, when I run with full compile, the changes work excellently.  I even tried making a debugging MsgBox but it doesn't show in the compiled EXE.  There are no errors during compilation.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Do you have an old EXE in the same directory?  If so,  make sure it is not read-only.

Comment: I would first check the exe file and make sure that you really made a new one.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked.  New EXE as of this afternoon. We deleted the old one

Comment: And you are using a direct SQL statement in a VB6 program, not a stored procedure?

Comment: Check that you are definitely running the EXE you think you are running. Use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check.

Comment: @BobRodes that is correct.  The SQL statement itself is stored as a string in the program.

Answer (score 2):

Like MarkJ said, I wasn't actually running the EXE I thought I was running.  When I checked it with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) , the actual EXE was running from AppData\Local\Temp, so I just deleted those EXEs, ran again, and everything worked excellently.  Thanks for the advice @MarkJ!

Comment: +1. Edited in a link to process explorer. And, you're welcome!